# Edit stage2.img

Tags: linux, centos, mount

I need to edit the stage2.img file to fix a glitch where kickstart wont allow you to select network or hostname options. But I cant for the life of me get the damn thing mounted.

mount -o loop,ro -t cramfs stage2.img /mnt/img/

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

dmesg | tail results in

cramfs: wrong magic

Anyone know what would be causing this? CentOS 5

Comment: Its not a cramfs; rather it is a squashfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to edit the `stage2.img`. You can create an `updates.img` and this will get copied over the stuff from the regular stage2. See docs at: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Updates